# Can I run several VPNs on iPadOS at once?

Tags: vpn, ipados

I’m not sure that I am using the correct terminology, but my question is whether or not I can have multiple personal VPN devices operating at once.

I have AdGuard, Microsoft Defender and Freedom all battling for control of my iPad network. Can I have them all running at once?

Comment: It would be helpful to include the version of the operating system on your (presumably) iPad. Also what you have already tried that has not worked.

Comment: Also, what is the intention here? Do you need VPN-specific routing, do you want to stack the ones running locally, or something else?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/microsoft-defender-endpoint-ios?view=o365-worldwide might offer a clue: "Running other third-party endpoint protection products alongside Defender for Endpoint on iOS is likely to cause performance problems and unpredictable system errors."

Comment: @SteveChambers- yes... my bad. iPadOS 17.3.1. I have "split tunneling" activated on Adguard, but that is it/all I can tell I can do. If I have Freedom on, it doesn't block ads, etc.

Comment: @nohillside- the latter, I think. I would like to have all of them working at the same time, instead of Freedom blocking sites but not ads, Defender doing whatever Defender does without interfering with the other two, etc.

Comment: @nohillside- well, poop. Thanks for the link, though 

Comment: My understanding: At any one time you can have one "Personal VPN" active alongside one "Device VPN". It would help if you gave the full App Store title of each product and whether they are classified as Personal or Device VPNs.

Comment: This is rather old https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180281/what-is-the-difference-between-personal-vpn-vs-vpn-configuration-profiles#180819 but it may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a personal iPhone without MDM, there are two classes of VPN - Personal and Device. One from each class can be active at the same time.

This is somewhat different to those in the answer from @bmike which is on a managed iPhone.

As an example, my iPhone has these VPNs:

[image]

"Personal" VPNs are network VPNs using inbuilt VPN protocols. In my case both are using the IKEv2 protocol to connect to two well known consumer VPN products. No surprises here for those familiar with established VPN protocols.

Only one of these can be active. In practice this is not an undue restriction.

"Device" VPNs are using Network Extensions for differing purposes.

In my case, I have those implementing Wireguard, ZeroTier and Tailscale VPN protocols for connection to my home network. These are protocols not implemented by Apple. I only have that many for fun/interest.

But Network Extensions can be used for other purposes, particularly those related to security.

I have the AdGuard Pro product which uses a Network Extension to intercept all DNS requests and reroute them to an AdGuard DNS server or another of my choice.

The question refers to other security products. These are all implemented as Network Extensions and will appear in the Device VPN list.

Only one Device VPN can be active.

The limitation on Device VPNs is annoyingly restrictive and prevents the questioner from running multiple security products. This restriction does not apply to macOS.

Here is a [VPN overview for Apple device deployment](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/deployment/depae3d361d0/web), but note it does not explore the restrictions on each platform.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - [iOS and iPadOS have some capability to have several VPN](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/vpn-overview-depae3d361d0/web), and most of these work best with MDM pushing configuration profiles to the device.

Even then, the system has one primary VPN connection and even if you configure three different VPN, only one can be active at any point in time (and none can be active).

Here is a company managed iPhone with two different primary VPN as well as two independent per-app VPN: one works for Safari and general Web requests and the other controls Chrome and Edge browsers. [It's set up similar to what's documented here - needing some enterprise level help with PKI and backend services.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/vpn-setting-configure-per-app)

On this device, you can have three different VPN engaged - the two per-app VPN which take priority over the apps they govern, and one of the system level VPN.

[image: iOS with two VPN configured and two per-app VPN additionally for a total of four VPN connections possible]

In your case, I am going to expect you can't have all three and instead need to look at per-app VPN to see if you can accomplish what you wish by layering the possible VPN on top of apps that need different settings and control.

Comment: Because your answer covers managed devices, I have added an answer more directly relevant to personal devices. It is intended as complementary, not competitive.

Comment: Thank you  - an excellent answer and I hope the OP selects yours as it's likely far more applicable to most.